# smart way to get data out of database through data access layer?

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, data-access-layer

I have a database with a lot of different datasets. I want to make it easy to search the different datasets depending on many different parameters, for example I currently have:

```
public List<Dataset> GetAllDatasetsByMethod(Method method)
```

with this query:

```
var datasets = from b in db.Method where b.Id == method.Id select b.Dataset;
```

and then I have another method looking like this:

```
public List<Dataset> GetAllDatasetsByTargetMaterial(TargetMaterial material)
```

and query like this:

```
var datasets = from b in db.Dataset
                where b.TargetMaterial.Name.ToLower() == material.Name.ToLower()
                select b;
```

I got a lot of these methods(like 10-15) comparing ether on an unique id or name. and I need to make more but I am starting to feel like I repeat myself and as far as I have learned [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself). So is there a smarter way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a class with all the different variations of query parameters, like

```
public class MyTypeQueryParameters
{
    public int? Id {get; set;}
    public string MaterialName {get; set;}
}
```

You can then design your data access layer like an internal API and have a method like:

```
public List<DataSet> GetDataSets(MyTypeQueryParameters parameters) {
    var query = db.DataSet.AsQueryable;
    if (parameters.Id != null) 
    {
        query = query.Where(x => x.Id == parameters.Id.Value);
    }

    if (!string.IsNullOrWhitespace(MaterialName))
    {
        query = query.Where(x => x.TargetMaterial.Name == parameters.MaterialName);
    }

    return query.ToList();
}
```

There are ways to clean up the method's logic a bit but that's how I would start off, so you don't end up with a ton of different methods that are all based on your query filters.

Comment: I have considered doing this, the problem for me is there are times where multiple conditions would have to be true(so find all with materialname and id at the same time for an example) wouldn't this just create one huge method instead with alot of if's?

Comment: Queries are composable, so you just have to take out the else statement in my example.  So if ID is specified you add the id where clause, and if the material name is specified you *also* add the where clause with the name.  If only one is present you only add the where clause for the only ones specified.  The query is not executed until you `.ToList()` it, so you can add as many `query = query.Where(x => whatever)` clauses you want.

Comment: Done.  All I did was remove the else keyword.  Now if both are specified the query will contain both where clauses.

Comment: Okay I see what you did i think, you get all datasets with given id and then also all datasets with given name. But I have times where both of those need to be true. so if both id and name were given it should return those datasets who have those two(so if there is a dataset with a method id but not a target material name then it shouldn't include it)? I wouldn't be able to do that this way would I ?

Comment: I think you are getting hung up on not understanding how IQueryables and EF work.  When I do `query = query.Where(x => x.Id == id)` I am NOT getting all the datasets from the database that have a matching ID.  What I am doing is forming a SQL query that will retrieve datasets with a matching ID, but I have only formed the query and not executed the query.  The second where clause then essentially adds an "AND" to the id query but still does not execute the query.  ToList() then executes the query with both where clauses inside.

Comment: ohhh you are totaly right, wow this is a lot smarter then! thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If method proliferation is your issue, and all you're doing is changing the where statement, you can use a Func as an argument and just provide the logic that you want as a func.

eg:

```
 public IEnumerable<MyType> GetAllDataSetBy<MyType>(Func<MyType,bool> func) {
      return db.DataSet.Where(b=>func(b));
 }
 public MyType GetSingle<MyType>(Func<MyType,bool> func) {
      return db.DataSet.Single(b=>func(b));
 }
```